# Scala how to split a list at a certain index

Tags: scala

If I have a list of ten elements in Scala how can I create a new list that consists of only the elements of the previous list from a range of two indexes. So if the original list was ten items long the new one could be like:

```
val N=Oldlist(0) to Oldlist(10)
```

Please do not use the split at method thats not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? Not very clear to me

Comment: Agreed - as it's written now, it just sounds like you are looking for [`slice(start, end)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@slice(from:Int,until:Int):List[A])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` has a `slice(from, to)` method. You should probably use that. I thought it used structural sharing, but it doesn't (as discussed in the comments).

Comment: "probably uses structural sharing" It doesn't (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1 - the code for take (which slice uses) creates new cons.

Comment: There is no way you could do structural sharing between two cons list except if both have the same end. So if would be possible only when slice is in fact just a drop (drop does structural sharing, of course) and doing it in that case would still be difficult, because, as the cons list's size is not available cheaply, you don't know immediately when calling slice whether the slice goes to the end.One could build a slice Seq that would be just a view, (probably actual drop, than create a take view) but that would not be a List, and it would prevent collection of the elements after `to`

Comment: Yeah I wasn't thinking about it as a recursive type. Thx for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you can do:

```
val list = (oldlist(0) to oldList(10)).toList
```

`oldlist(0) to oldList(10)` creates a new [`Range`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range) that is then converted to a `List`.